# change multiindex level: "ValueError: On level 0, code max >= length of level"

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am having a hard time changing some code that was adjusting the `'date'` part of a `MultiIndex` to `MonthEnd` like this (relying on the fact that the `'date'` part was at position 0):

```py
offset = pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0] + offset, level=0, inplace=True)
```

The `inplace` argument is marked as deprecated in `pandas=1.2.1` (and for good reasons, I'm all in favor).

While refactoring the code, I figured I would also like to use a named level (`'date'`), rather than the `int` level (`0`), for easier readability and maintainability. So, I wrote:

```py
level = 'date'
mi = df.index
df = df.set_index(mi.set_level(mi.unique(level) + offset, level=level)
```

That worked nicely, until it encountered a `df` that was a copy of another one with a subset of the `MultiIndex`.

Consider the following set up for a minimal example:

```py
def get_example_df(notbefore=None):
    np.random.seed(0)
    n = 3
    dates = pd.date_range('2000', freq='MS', periods=n)
    names = list('ab')
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(10, size=n * len(names)),
        columns=['x'],
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, names],
                                         names=('date', 'name'))
    )
    if notbefore:
        dates = df.index.get_level_values('date')
        df = df.loc[dates >= notbefore]
    return df


level = 'date'
offset = pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
```

Without truncation, all is well:

```py
>>> df = get_example_df()
>>> df
                 x
date       name   
2000-01-01 a     5
           b     0
2000-02-01 a     3
           b     3
2000-03-01 a     7
           b     9

# note:
>>> df.index.codes[0]
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int8)

>>> mi = df.index
>>> df.set_index(mi.set_levels(mi.unique(level) + offset, level=level))
                 x
date       name   
2000-01-31 a     5
           b     0
2000-02-29 a     3
           b     3
2000-03-31 a     7
           b     9
```

However, when the `MultiIndex` is a view (because of `notbefore` being not `None`), then it goes rather badly:

```py
>>> df = get_example_df(notbefore='2000-02-15')
>>> df
                 x
date       name   
2000-03-01 a     7
           b     9

>>> mi = df.index
>>> df.set_index(mi.set_levels(mi.unique(level) + offset, level=level))
...
ValueError: On level 0, code max (2) >= length of level (1). NOTE: this index is in an inconsistent state
```

It turns out that the problem is that the `mi.codes[0]` don't start at 0 when the `df` is the truncated one:

```py
>>> df.index.codes[0]
array([2, 2], dtype=int8)
```

So we have the unfortunate situation that:

```py
>>> len(df.index.levels[0])
3

>>> len(df.index.get_level_values(level))
2

>>> len(df.index.unique(level))
1
```

and the only one that can be assigned (after adding the `offset`) back to the level is `df.index.levels[0]`.

The only thing I can figure for my new code that seems to reliably work is:

```py
level_idx = df.index.names.index('date')
# level_idx is now 0
mi = df.index
mi = mi.set_levels(mi.levels[level_idx] + offset, level=level_idx)
```

And now:

```py
>>> mi
MultiIndex([('2000-03-31', 'a'),
            ('2000-03-31', 'b')],
           names=['date', 'name'])

>>> mi.codes[0]
array([2, 2], dtype=int8)  # as before
```

That feels wrong. It would be good to have a `.set_unique()` that would be a robust counterpart to `.unique()`, even if `.codes` don't start at 0.  It is also inefficient (e.g. when there are much fewer `.unique()` values than the full length of the `MultiIndex`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe you may need to remove the unused levels [`remove_unused_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html)  but just confirming `df1 =get_example_df(notbefore='2000-02-15')` ,   `mi = df1.index.remove_unused_levels()` then 
`df1.set_index(mi.set_levels(mi.unique(level) + offset, level=level))` ?

Comment: Excellent!  If you could post that as an answer so I can accept and uptick.

Comment: how portable is that, do you happen to know?  (I mean, we support pandas as far back as `pandas>=0.24`)

Comment: It is supported from `0.20.0.` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

based on our discussion, I think you may want to remove the [`unused levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

This was new in pandas version: `New in version 0.20.0.`

```
mi = df1.index.remove_unused_levels()
df1.set_index(mi.set_levels(mi.unique(level) + offset, level=level))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

def get_example_df(notbefore=None):
    np.random.seed(0)
    n = 3
    dates = pd.date_range('2000', freq='MS', periods=n)
    names = list('ab')
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(10, size=n * len(names)),
        columns=['x'],
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, names],
                                     names=('date', 'name'))
    )
    if notbefore:
        dates = df.index.get_level_values('date')
        df = df.loc[dates >= notbefore]
    return df

df=get_example_df()
endOfMonth=[pd.to_datetime(x[0].strftime("%Y-%m"))+MonthEnd(1) for x in df.index]
df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
df['date']=endOfMonth
df=df.set_index(['date','name'])
print(df)



 date       name  x 
 2000-01-31 a     5
            b     0
 2000-02-29 a     3
            b     3
 2000-03-31 a     7
            b     9
```